# How to make system wide Gnome menus with alacarte?

Tags: linux, gnome

When I have edited the Gnome menu with `alacarte` as root, I do

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p /etc/my-gnome-menus
rm -rf /etc/my-gnome-menus/*

cp -r /root/.config/menus /etc/my-gnome-menus/
cp -r /root/.local/share/applications /etc/my-gnome-menus/share/
cp -r /root/.local/share/desktop-directories /etc/my-gnome-menus/share/
```

and add this to `/etc/environment`

```
XDG_CONFIG_HOME="/etc/my-gnome-menus"
XDG_DATA_HOME="/etc/my-gnome-menus/share"
```

but I don't see the changes I have made system wide.

Do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rm -r /root/.local/share
rm -r /root/.config/menus

mkdir -p /etc/my-gnome-menus

echo 'XDG_CONFIG_HOME="/etc/my-gnome-menus"' >> /etc/environment
echo 'XDG_DATA_HOME="/etc/my-gnome-menus/share"' >> /etc/environment
```

Now use `alacarte` to edit the menus.